# ImageMagick script to resize folder of images

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a folder of images of varying sizes and quality.  Is there a way with ImageMagic that I could automatically resize them to be no bigger 1100px x 1100px and less than 160kb.  And not to re-size if they are smaller than those parameters.  Also not to distort the image so it fits within but to only re-size so for example an image which is 2200px by 1000px would become 1100px by 500px.

I'm working on Ubuntu with ImageMagick 6.7.7-10.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on a copy of your files:

```
mogrify -define jpeg:extent=160k -resize 1100x1100\> *.jpg
```

I am assuming your files are JPEG images. The command will largely work for other image types too, but it can only enforce the 160kB limit for JPEG files - not PNG, or TIFF etc.

**Example**

With version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-08-06

```
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:gray +noise random a.jpg

ls -lrt a.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  6969601 21 Aug 18:28 a.jpg            # <--- 7MB

mogrify -define jpeg:extent=160k -resize 1100x1100\> a.jpg

ls -lrt a.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  147938 21 Aug 18:28 a.jpg             # <--- 160kB

identify a.jpg
a.jpg JPEG 1100x1100 1100x1100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 148KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: that only resized them, it did not reduce the file size.  I was able to almost get the result I wanted with `mogrify -path .  -resize 1100x1100\> -quality 85% *.jpg`, although for some files 85% is too little and possible too much

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org , what version have you got

Comment: Whe I run the command the file size goes down to approx 1.6mb on some of the files, not 160kb

Comment: Please try upgrading, the command should definitely work as I gave it.

Comment: I think I have the latest version.  When I run `sudo apt-get install ImageMagick` it says `imagemagick is already the newest version`

Comment: Given that mine is over a year and many revisions newer, I think not. Maybe you `apt-get` isn't looking in the best place.

Comment: The date presented by ImageMagick's -version is misleading.  It's the date it was compiled.  The actual release date for your version (6.7.7-10) is 2012-06-28  according to the ChangeLog.